# Can Web Notification works like push notification service?

Tags: html, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I've checked W3C Web Notification standard document. But, I can't find that server side specifications. And, I still don't understand that it can wake up the web browser.  What I understand is web notification can draw a notification box on the Browser, when user on a web site.

Is if possible that a web site push a notification message to a web browser (on a mobile device) that does not launched? I know Safari on MAC can do that through APNs. How about HTML5 web notification? Can it cover whole part of Push notification solutions? (APNs on iOS, GCM on Android)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its pretty much possible to push notification from web site to web browser,
you can leverage client side java script for users consent and registration and server side process to push the notification to users based some business event.

Client Side -
Register your service worker (most of modern browser supports it-

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function (status) {
        if (status === 'denied') {
        \\You can add logging here
        }
        else if (status === 'granted') {
          initialiseServiceWorker();
        }
}
function initialiseServiceWorker() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js', { scope: './' })
        .then(handleSWRegistration)
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('[initialiseServiceWorker] : req.register serviceWorker unable to get serviceWorker file.', err);
        });
};

function handleSWRegistration(event) {
    if (event.installing) {
        console.log('[handleSWRegistration] : Service worker installing');
    } else if (event.waiting) {
        console.log('[handleSWRegistration] : Service worker installed');
    } else if (event.active) {
        console.log('[handleSWRegistration] : Service worker active');
    }
}
```

Server Side-

You can use any of server side implementation [GitHub](https://github.com/web-push-libs) Nuget
below snippet from one of C# library implementation-

```
var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails("mailto:abcw@abc.com", _vapidPublicKey, _vapidPrivateKey);
var pushSubscription = new PushSubscription(PushEndpoint, PushP256DH, PushAuth);

var payLoad = new
                {
                    message = $"Hello from Notification.",
                    title = "Notification!"
                };
string strPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payLoad);

webPushClient.SendNotification(pushSubscription, strPayload, options);
```

You can refer this link for architectural flow-

[PushNotification](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications-slides)

Comment: you may review now trincot.

Answer (score 0):

If you can allow your application to run in background without terminating you can poll the server for notification continuously.. But if your application is not launched or not running in that case its not possible without APN as Apple push notification server is allowed to deliver the notification to notificationcenter of the device intended for a particular application..

Answer (score 0):

I've found these three articles for my question's answer.

1. Push notification for sleeped web browser is possible. FireFox OS already do it.
   [FF Push Service](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/07/dont-miss-out-on-the-real-time-fun-use-firefox-os-push-notifications/)
2. Web Push service's reference Document and W3C Standard are here. But, there is no spec for Server. Server implementation is depends on Browser maker.
   [FireFox OS Simple Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager)  [W3C Push API](http://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/)